# Angular2 render template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have two components, ComponentA uses ComponentB. ComponentB is a table which can retrieve data, options and a template which defines the table content.
I want ComponentB to be a Component to render different tables. I have no idea how to render templates in Angular2 v2.1.0. I found stuff like DynamicComponentLoader and ComponentResolver which are both obsolete. What components does Angular2 2.1.0 provide to render templates?

ComponentA :

```
@Component({
    'template':<my-table [template]="template" [options]="options" [data]="data"></mytable>
)}
export class ViewA{
  template:string;
  ngOnInit(){
      this.template = `
          <tr
           *ngFor="let item of items">
             <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          </tr>
      `
  }
}
```

ComponentB:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-table',
'template':`
   <table>
     <thead>
        <th *ngFor="let conf of config.columns">
            {{conf.title}}
        </th>
     </thead>
     <tbody #tBody>
     </tbody>
   </table>
`
)}
export class ViewB{
@Input('template') template:string;
@Input('data') data:MyData;
@Input('options') options:MyOptions;

constructor(){
    //todo: create template element, append template element into the tbody element
}
```

}
}